# Simple C++ logging class - ostream reference initialization

Tags: c++, logging, reference, cout, ostream

I've read several similar questions here that have been answered, but I don't grok yet, so please bear that in mind before closing as duplicate :).  I want a simple Log object with a Print() method.  If Log is constructed with no parameters, logging is to cout.  Otherwise, parameters describe a file to which logging is done.

(I suspect part of the problem is understanding the relationship between all the `stream` classes.)

When compiled, error is:

```
Log.cpp:11:23: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’
```

Log.h:

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Log {

public:
    Log();
    Log(const char*, const char*);

    void Print(const char*  msg,...);

private:
    // instance contains a reference to ostream
    std::ofstream&  output_stream;
};

#endif
```

Log.cpp:

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <fstream>

// Constructor w/no parms = log to cout
Log::Log() :
    output_stream(cout)
{}

// Constructor w/parms = log to file
Log::Log(const char* dir, const char* file) {
    string output_file_name = string(dir) + "/" + string(file);
    output_stream.open(output_file_name.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
}

// Print() sends output to the stream (we'll do printf semantics later)
void
Log::Print(const char* msg,...) {
    output_stream << msg << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cout` is not of type `ofstream`, so you cannot bind an `ofstream` reference to it.  `output_stream` should be type `ostream&` instead, which will allow it to refer to either `cout` and a file stream, since `ofstream` is a subclass of `ostream`.

Also, in the case that the user provides a filename, you still need something for the reference to refer to, you can't just use it as is.  I recommend that you store an actual `ofstream` object, (or a `unique_ptr<ofstream>`), and make `output_stream` refer to it.  Make sure you declare the `ofstream` object *before* the `ostream` reference in your class definition, otherwise you will have undefined behavior when you try to bind the reference in the initialization list.  Or you can make it a pointer, instead of a reference, and assign it in the body of the constructor.

Comment: +1 excellent note on the important of the member order and initializer list. For the OP's benefit, [see this snippet](http://ideone.com/6crvUs).

Comment: This explanation led me to a solution.  One question: when I declared [or is it defined?] `Log logger("/path/to", "logfile");`, it worked. When I wrote `Log logger();`, the compiler complained that `request for member ‘Print’ in ‘logger’, which is of non-class type ‘Log()’`.  When I wrote `Log logger;`, it worked.  What is `Log logger()` saying?

Comment: @Chap: `Log logger();` is parsed as the declaration of a function named "logger", which takes no arguments and returns a `Log` object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest shuffling `filebuf`s or other `streambuf`s.

```
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

class Log {

public:
    Log();
    Log(const char*, const char*);

    void Print(const char*  msg,...);

private:
    // instance contains a reference to ostream
    std::ostream  output_stream;
    std::ofstream _file;
};
```

And the `cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

// Constructor w/no parms = log to cout
Log::Log()
    : output_stream(std::cout.rdbuf())
{}

// Constructor w/parms = log to file
Log::Log(const char* dir, const char* file) 
    : output_stream(nullptr)
{
    std::string output_file_name = std::string(dir) + "/" + std::string(file);
    _file.open(output_file_name.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
    output_stream.rdbuf(_file.rdbuf());
}

// Print() sends output to the stream (we'll do printf semantics later)
void Log::Print(const char* msg,...) {
    output_stream << msg << std::endl;
}
```